# Parse-Server Cloud code issues accessing req.params

Tags: parse-server

Maybe I'm doing this wrong but how would I access query parameters of Cloud functions?

When I do a POST here (as cloud functions work) and add my query parameter of "q" it says it is undefined.

Here's the URL I am POST'ing to

http://localhost:1337/api/v1/functions/get_untappd?q=45566

From the url I build up you can see at the end I'm using the typical Express.js / Node accessing of parameters.

```
var untappdURL = "https://api.untappd.com/v" + 
                  untappdApiVersion + 
                  "/search/beer?client_id=" + 
                  untappdClientId + 
                  "&client_secret=" + 
                  untappdClientSecret + 
                  "&q=" + request.params.q;
```

Anything I'm doing wrong?

Comment: That looks correct. Can you share the code you are using as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I should of closed this out. It was a bug and they eventually fixed it =]